# JavaScript Pattern Matching with Asterisks

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make something that would check if a string like this:

`https://www.example.com/page`

Is equal to:

`http*//*example.com/*`

Or something like this.
Is there something built in to JS that does this with asterisks, or should I use a plugin or something?

Comment: Just to be precise, what you're looking for is 'wildcard matching', and the `*` is the wildcard. You can't do that out of the box, but have a look at the answer below for a solution with regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to create a function that does this, but thank you all for your answers. I will post the code below.

```
var wildcardCheck = function(i, m) {
   var regExpEscape = function(s) {
       return s.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&');
   };
   var m = new RegExp('^' + m.split(/\*+/).map(regExpEscape).join('.*') + '$');
   return i.match(m) !== null && i.match(m).length >= 1;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in that does what you've literally described. But look at [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), which are the generalized version. The regular expression in your case would probably be `/^http.*\/\/.*example\.com.*$/`.

Example:

```js
var rex = /^http.*\/\/.*example\.com.*$/;
function test(str) {
  console.log(str, rex.test(str));
}
test("https://www.example.com/page"); // true
test("ttps://www.example.com/page");  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `match()` function

- Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

```js
let str = 'https://www.example.com/page';

let strMatches  = str.match( /http([\s\S]*?)\/\/([\s\S]*?)example.com([\s\S]*?)/ );

let result = document.querySelector('#result');
if( strMatches!= null && strMatches.length > 0 ){
  result.innerHTML = 'Match';
} else {
    result.innerHTML = 'Mismatch';
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```